# Liferay: Checking permissions based on role

Tags: liferay

I'd like to check if the logged in user has permission to execute a certain action on a portlet. Let's say there is a "Create Product" button on a page and I'd like to hide it if anyone other than the admin is logged in. How do you check for that, both in the front end  and back end

Answer (score 2):

You should check it in the front end and also in the back end. For this purpose you can use the PermissionChecker. http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.0/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/security/permission/PermissionChecker.html

Edit:

You can find some examples here: http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/development/-/ai/security-and-permissions

Comment: Are there any examples of how I can use this? I'm using JSF for the Portlet display.